# Rewrite string with $j for php 7.2

Tags: php

Whith 7.2 php some writing of code will change. 
I have trouble rewriting it.
What is the correct code for  `${slot.$j}` now ?

```
$j = 1;
$slot1 = 80;
echo ${slot.$j};
```

**Result: 80**

> Warning: Use of undefined constant slot - assumed 'slot' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in ......\TA\test.php on
>   line 7

Comment: `echo "slot{$j}";` ... or just `echo "slot$j";` ... but that's not a PHP 7.2 thing, it looks as if the original code would be wrong in *any* version of PHP

Comment: echo ${"slot".$j};  - check o/p: https://3v4l.org/DYfE2

Comment: @BhaskarJain - aaaaaah, *thats* what the OP was trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not for php version 7.2 or all that. You can try any of the below ways-

```
<?php
$j = 1;
$slot1 = 80;
echo ${"slot{$j}"}; // result: 80
echo PHP_EOL;
echo ${"slot$j"}; // result: 80
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/qqqV3